# 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306'

Tags: python, mysql, ssl, mysql-python

I keep facing this error - connection drops at times. 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306', system error: 1 [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2536)

I am using python flask to interact with mysql db. I already close connection like this.

```
def __exit__(self):
    if self.connDB:
        self.cursor.close()
        self.connDB.close()
```

I already followed some of the solutions available but is still not working.

Also some context, I previously was using mysql docker. MySQL docker has some breaking changes. So I decided to revert to downloading and using mysql locally.

I appreciate everyone's help as this issue is impeding my development progress.

Comment: remove the ssl_key and ssl_cert connection arguments

Comment: disable the ssl in the connection string and if need be, also in the server on locaLhost it serves no purpose, there are also newer alternative connectors for python

Comment: I did not input any ssl info in the connection arguments.. @nbk

Comment: then check the configuration of the server, if it has ssl enabled

Comment: @nbk, what if for security concern, I do not want to disable since it will be in the production environment? I have to input ssl arguements? What are the newer alternative connectors for python?

Comment: an attacker on the system can access everything, he will not start wireshark and look at the raw data. as i sid in my first comment, the problem lies in the ssl version of the key, so generate a new key pair, if the key isn't 1.2 or 1.3 maybe your system is too old.